# Download a website that doesnt exist anymore, but I have opened in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, memory, download, tabs

I need to use a Yield farm website that has been deleted because it was a scam. Unfortunatly for the scammers, I have the website opened in Chrome and it is working and fully operative in this state (if I move from that place, clicking on another link, everything will dissapear forever...)

Is there any way to download the current status of the website? Probably all the elements are now somewhere in Chrome memory because I can use it, but if my PC crashes or I accidentally refresh the page, it wont work again.